# Vertx discovers node but cannot see message

Tags: vert.x

When I start a new `clusteredVertx`, the cluster manager finds other nodes on the network, but the distributed `eventBus` can't see messages published on a test address.

For example, on starting up a new node:

```
VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();

Vertx.clusteredVertx(options, res -> {
if (res.succeeded()) {
  Vertx vertx = res.result();
}
```

autodiscovers the other node(s)

```
Members [4] {
  Member [192.168.21.51]:5702
  Member [192.168.21.51]:5703
  Member [192.168.21.51]:5701
  Member [192.168.25.8]:5701 this
}
```

but then when a JsonObject message is published on channel "test" like this:

```
eventBus eB1 = vertx.eventBus()
JsonObject j = new JsonObject();
j.put("test1", "test2");
eB1.publish("test", j);
```

it isn't being picked up by a receiver on another node.

```
EventBus eB2 = vertx.eventBus();
System.out.println("Receiver start");
MessageConsumer<JsonObject> testChannel = eB2.consumer("test");
testChannel.handler(message -> {
  System.out.println("Received: " + message.body().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution, from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vertx/q4gIHvDuC8s) was to set the cluster option to the local node.

```
String ipAddress = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
VertxOptions options = new VertxOptions();
options.setClusterHost(ipAddress);
```